# ASP.Net Impersonation in integrated mode on IIS7.5

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7.5, windows-authentication, impersonation

We have recently discovered that our IIS server is not correctly impersonating the authorised users, and this only works correctly in `Classic` mode, not `integrated` mode.

To give this context, I'll detail our setup..

We have an Informix database, which due to reasons outside of this question, we are connecting to using ODBC and windows authentication.

ODBC is setup to use the authenticated user to connect to the Informix database, where that is setup to allow users authenticated in that fashion.

What doesn't appear to be happening is that IIS is impersonating the thread, and it is trying to authenticate with ODBC/IFX as the application pool user, not the windows user.

Is there an IIS/ASP.net setting which needs to be setup?

As I mentioned, this works as expected in `Classic` mode, but I understand that we should be trying to use `Integrated` mode moving forwards

Comment: Can you get away with running the site as Classic mode? I know there where [breaking changes](http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/building-and-running-aspnet-applications/aspnet-20-breaking-changes-on-iis) with the introduction of ASP.NET 2.0 in & around that area.

Comment: I think we `can` run it in Classic mode, it's just slightly concerning..

Comment: Actually.. running it in Classic mode causes issues with Resouces/Handers (notably MiniProfiler)